# essential singularities and poles (sum and product of functions)

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z_0 = 0$ and $h(z)$ has a pole at $z_0 = 0$, how can it be proven that both $f(z) + h(z)$ and $f(z)h(z)$ have essential singularities at $z_0 = 0$?

I have not worked much with classification of singularities at this point and I'm genuinely stuck.

Comment: Have you discussed the behavior of functions in a neighborhood of a removable singularity/pole/essential singularity? What can you say about the limit of $f(z)+h(z)$ as $z \to 0$ if it were to have a pole, for example?